# How to authenticate to Cloud Storage from a Docker app on Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run, google-container-registry

I have a Node.js app in a Docker container that I'm trying to deploy to Google Cloud Run.

**I want my app to be able to read/write files from my GCS buckets that live under the same project**, and I haven't been able to find much information around it.

This is what I've tried so far:

#### 1. Hoping it works out of the box

A.k.a. initializing without credentials, like in App Engine.

```js
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// ...later in an async function

const storage = new Storage();

// This line throws the exception below
const [file] = await storage.bucket('mybucket')
  .file('myfile.txt')
  .download()
```

The last line throws this exception

```
{ Error: Could not refresh access token: Unsuccessful response status code. Request failed with status code 500"
    at Gaxios._request (/server/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:85:23)
```

#### 2. Hoping it works out of the box after setting the Storage Admin IAM role to my Cloud Run service accounts.

Nope. No difference with previous.

#### 3. Copying my credentials file as a `cloudbuild.yaml` step:

```
...
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    args: ['cp', 'gs://top-secret-bucket/gcloud-prod-credentials.json', '/www/gcloud-prod-credentials.json']
...
```

It copies the file just fine, but then the file is nor visible from my app. I'm still not sure where exactly it was copied to, but listing the `/www` directory from my app shows no trace of it.

#### 4. Copy my credentials file as a Docker step

Wait, but for that I need to authenticate `gsutil`, and for that I need the credentials.

#### So...

What options do I have without uploading my credentials file to version control?

Comment: Looking here ... https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity we are told that there are "application default credentials".    What GCS roles did you assign to what credentials and what was the effect?

Comment: This is an example where showing your code helps get an answer. How are you setting up the credentials in your code?

Comment: @John Hanley, I can't find a way to make those credentials available to my app (other than pushing them to the repo, which we don't want). I edited the question and added a code example. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Kolban, I tried setting these roles:

`Service Account Token Creator`,
`Storage Admin`

to all these accounts:

`[myprojectid]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`,
`[myprojectid]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`,
`[myprojectid]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com`.

Still getting the `Could not refresh access token` error.

Do you know what role I need to assign to what account?

Comment: This seems to be the core of the story ...https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity  ... from this I sense that [PROJECT-NUMBER]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com  is the identity that Cloud Rub uses for ADC.

Comment: I tried to recreate and couldn't.  Mine worked.

Comment: @Kolban you were right. I had my Compute Engine default service account disabled from previous experiments. I enabled it and made sure the same account had the "Storage Object Admin" role assigned. After that, it works as it's supposed to. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, If you found the solution, could you post it as an answer and accept it? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to make it work:

- The code for initializing the client library was correct. No changes here from the original question. You don't need to load any credentials if the GCS bucket belongs to the same project as your Cloud Run service.
- I learned that the service account `[myprojectid]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` (aka "Compute Engine default service account") is the one used by default for running the Cloud Run service unless you specify a different one.
- I went to the [Service Accounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) page and made sure that the mentioned service account was enabled (mine wasn't, this was what I was missing).
- Then I went [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam), edited the permissions for the mentioned service account and added the Storage Object Admin role.

More information on this article: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way is to change to a custom service account that has the desired permissions. You can do this under the 'Security' tab when deploying a new revision.

[image]